# Moving variables from one file to the other in React JS

Tags: reactjs, variables, import, export

I'm a noob with React JS and I'm trying to understand how to export a variable from a file and import it into another. What I tried is this:

File App.js:

```
import React from 'react'


function App() {

  [hi, setUpHi] = useState('Hello World')

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Test /> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
export {hi}
```

File Test.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import {hi} from './App'

function Test() {
    return (
        <div>
            {hi}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test
```

But this doesn't work :(
It says that hi is not defined. I tried to define it outside of the function, this also doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

ps:

I know that I could do it easier by using props:

```
<Test hi = {'Hello World'} />
```

and then

```
function Test({hi}) ... \\ etc.
```

But with this example, I want to understand how to export and import variables, which might be much easier than passing props. (Or am I wrong with this assumption?)

Comment: What you are trying to do is an anti pattern . So you are trying to export a state which should be known only to that component . `[hi, setUpHi] = useState('Hello World')` doing this will add hi and setUpHi as a properly in your global window object .  If you want only component to receive value from other component then in react it should always be via props .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to reference the "hi" variable outside of it's function scope (it's declared in the component, not at root level) - hence why it's undefined in the global scope.

Also, FYI it's an antipattern to use component state in this way. State is internal to the FunctionComponent App and exposing it's state in this way could compromise component purity.

If your intention is to share state between components, either pass them through props, or use a custom hook.